# How to block annoying facebook and other social network widgets

Tags: firefox, blocking, widgets, social-networking

We have facebook buttons, twitter buttons, linkedin buttons, google+ buttons, stumbleupon buttons, younameit buttons. These social network buttons and widgets are creeping up the internets like the plague. Sometimes even with cool javascript popups which obscure content if moused over.

How can I get rid of them?

I mean stuff like this:

[image: annoying social network buttons on arstechnica.com]

and this:

[image: annoying social network buttons on 9gag.com]

and last but not least, this:

[image: annoying social network buttons on superuser.com]

How can I get rid of them?

Comment: Sounds like you're pretty tired of "Social Disease" networking, eh?

Comment: Oh and another thing, isn't it cute when they're added as floating toolbars that obscure content?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's pretty simple with the Adblock Plus, here see this tutorial - http://www.techairlines.com/2010/12/12/block-social-buttons-widgets/

short summary:

1. Install [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/)
2. Install this filter: https://monzta.maltekraus.de/adblock_social.txt

Answer (score 11):

Apart from using a classic ad blocker and defining your own rules, I've found [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) quite helpful. It blocks *most* of these add-ons, like Facebook Connect and Twitter, also Google Analytics and all kinds of ad networks.

[image]

The idea behind it is to stop those massive ad networks from tracking your browsing habits.

Comment: I would somehow feel better about this answer if the front page for Ghostery didn't prominently feature: "Follow Us On Twitter" and "Friend Us on Facebook." :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Haha, yeah. I thought the same. But they don't embed any Facebook connect buttons.

Comment: I have not seen this add-on before, but it looks interesting. +1

Answer (score 5):

The **[Fanboy Annoyance Block List](http://www.fanboy.co.nz/)** for [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/master/README.md#philosophy), [AdBlock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/) or any other browser extension that can use AdBlock Plus filter lists in Firefox or Chrome...

> ...Blocks Social Media Content, In page Pop-Ups and other annoyances; thereby substantially decreasing web page loading times and uncluttering them.

I personally prefer the Fanboy Annoyances block list to the Antisocial list, as it blocks more than just social media content (also in-page popups, newsletters, unnecessary links, self promos and other content that clutters sites unnecessarily). See a [comparison between the Antisocial and the Fanboy Annoyance Block List here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U40O8.jpg).

...Or, you could install the **[Fanboy Ultimate List](https://secure.fanboy.co.nz/filters.html)**, which combines the Annoyances block list with [EasyPrivacy](https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) (blocks trackers), and [EasyList](https://easylist.adblockplus.org/en/) (main ad blocking list; a lot of ads are also trackers).

The [**Anti-Facebook Filters**](https://www.fanboy.co.nz/) might also be of interest. It is specifically for blocking Facebook content.

Answer (score 3):

Try the [Disconnect addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disconnect/) for Firefox.

> If you’re a typical web user, you’re unintentionally sending your
>   browsing history with your name and other personal information to
>   third parties whenever you’re online.
>
> Take control of the data you share with Disconnect!
>
> Disconnect lets you:
>
> - Disable tracking by third parties like Digg, Facebook, Google, Twitter, and Yahoo, without requiring any setup or significantly
>     degrading the usability of the web.
> - See how many resource requests are blocked, in real time.
> - Easily unblock services, by clicking the toolbar button then services (and reloading current pages) — e.g., so you can play games
>     on Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Ghostery`. The addon is available for both Firefox & Chrome.
Ghostery sees the "invisible" web, detecting trackers, web bugs, pixels, and beacons placed on web pages by Facebook, Google Analytics, and over 500 other ad networks, behavioral data providers, web publishers - all companies interested in your activity. 

[Firefox Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/)

[Chrome Addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ghostery/mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij?hl=en)