# Adblock-like plugin for hiding social sites' widgets, buttons, etc

Tags: browser-addons, facebook, twitter, adblock, social-networking

I love Adblock plugins, and install them on a variety of browsers. They hide or remove ads, which take out a lot of clutter from sites.

However, I was thinking, is there any Adblock-like plugin (the more cross-browser the better, currently using Chrome, but my Girlfriend is between Firefox and Opera) that hides social widgets, buttons, and the like?

The only social thing I don't want to remove is comments (such as the [disqus](http://disqus.com/) ones), because most of the time they are meaningful to the content, but far too many sites have a horrible amount of ["Like me"](http://www.facebook.com/), ["Follow me"](http://twitter.com/) ["Plus me"](https://plus.google.com/) and so on. Some even have a [terribly distractive bird](http://www.mybloggertricks.com/2011/05/add-cute-flying-twitter-bird-to-your.html) that wants you to follow them at all costs by flying in front of what you want to read.

So what I want is a plugin that hides or removes: like/follow/plus buttons and counters, tweet feeds, social site sharing and bookmarking buttons (StumbleUpon, Reddit, etc), "mail to a friend", vertical tabs [(literally) left and right](http://anupamsaha.wordpress.com/2012/02/02/how-to-implement-floating-facebook-sidebar/), little "cute" effing blue birds flying on the screen, etc.

[image: Too Social]

I mean, something is wrong with my internets!

### Edit:

Using [lupincho's suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/391556/adblock-like-plugin-for-hiding-social-sites-widgets-buttons-etc/391563#391563) (an [Adblock subscription](http://abp:subscribe?location=https://adversity.googlecode.com/hg/Antisocial.txt&title=Antisocial)), The result is the following:

[image: An improvement]

Actually, there's still a lot of remainders in that page, so that page is now my test: the plugin that does the best cleaning job is the one I'll accept (even if it only works for one browser of the set Chrome|Firefox|Opera).

Please navigate to [this page](http://zailab.blogspot.com/) to see the use case.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/361378/how-to-block-annoying-facebook-and-other-social-network-widgets

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **[Fanboy Annoyance Block List](http://www.fanboy.co.nz/)** for [AdBlock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/en/) in Opera, Firefox and Chrome:

> Blocks Social Media Content, In page Pop-Ups and other annoyances; thereby substantially decreasing web page loading times and uncluttering them.

Comment: @CamiloMartin I prefer the Fanboy Annoyances block list to the Antisocial list, as it blocks more than just social media content (also in-page popups, newsletters, unnecessary links, self promos and other content that clutters sites unnecessarily). See a comparison between the two [here (link)](http://forums.fanboy.co.nz/forums/viewtopic.php?p=33347#p33347).

Comment: Oh, that comparison is very interesting, and this does look like something I would use. A great find, and since I'll likely forget to choose this as an answer instead (after some time using it), I'll tick it now.

Comment: This does not block facebook comment thread plugin.

Comment: @tumchaaditya You can report that at the EasyList forums, maybe they could fix that: http://forums.lanik.us/viewforum.php?f=62 Also, try [Ghostery](https://superuser.com/a/391563/10259).

Answer (score 8):

[Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/) does that; works with all major browsers.

Also, the "Antisocial" [subscription](https://adblockplus.org/en/subscriptions) for AdblockPlus.

Comment: Ghostery seems privacy-oriented, that's nice, but how does it block social sites' widgets? I'd like something designed for that purpose. I'll try the "Antisocial" subscription though, if it works as intended it's my choice.

Comment: Please see my edit of the question.

Comment: For widgets and other scripts, on Firefox you could try NoScript: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/. A combination of some or all of Ghostery, NoScript and Adblock Plus, possibly with custom filters, should work. But that's for Firefox; I don't know about other browsers.

Comment: NoScript is a nuclear option... Also, some sites would completely break without javascript. At any rate, in lack of any alternative that does a better job on that page, I'll accept your "Antisocial" subscription.

Comment: NoScript has a whitelist; you could disable it per-site.

Comment: Still, the trouble of having to mantain a whitelist puts me off. Nothing against it if you use it, of course (and it's on-topic as a suggestion, it may help someone).

Comment: Yes, it works for me because there are very few sites that I care about and that don't work without scripts enabled. But obviously it depends on the browsing habits.

Comment: I ended up with the antisocial subscription. After all, its name matches my social behavior :) By the way, it blocked [a recent xkcd comic](http://xkcd.com/1025/) for containing the word "tumblr", I think :P

Answer (score 2):

For Firefox, I use the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) add-on and the [Remove Facebook Like buttons (mod1)](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/93724) script.

Comment: But it only works for facebook, right? I don't like anything social.

Comment: It works for some others as well. I don't like any of those buttons, either, but this script is the closest I've found to something that will block all of them and it's a start. You might find something more comprehensive at userscripts.org. I haven't searched there recently.

Comment: The name is misleading, I thought it only worked for facebook. Still, it so far seems to be doing much the same as the Adblock "Antisocial" subscription. I'll keep trying to find a site where it hides something the other didn't, but so far it seems like a draw (and I prefer the subscription since there's no extra js to run).