# How can I block social share buttons in webpages

Tags: firefox, adblock, web-filtering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to block annoying facebook and other social network widgets](https://superuser.com/questions/361378/how-to-block-annoying-facebook-and-other-social-network-widgets)

A great many pages have these "Like", "Tweet", "G+1", "share" row of buttons all over the place and in each post in threads.

I do not use any of these services, am not interested, and find it distracting. I want to treat these elements the same as unsolicited web advertisements or Google text ads, i.e. remove them.

Is there a way to do this?

I am using firefox 14.0.1. and AdBlock Lite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe there is an Adblock subscription available [here](https://adblockplus.org/en/subscriptions) at the bottom of the page named Antisocial *(not affiliated)* which should remove most social media elements (buttons etc.) from browsing.

There is another called the Fanboy Annoyance Block List (available [here](http://www.fanboy.co.nz/)) which might also do the job and removes some social popups etc too.

There's finally something called Ghostery, mentioned in a previous question, although I have no idea if it works for social media elements (link [here](http://www.ghostery.com/)).

Hopefully one of these solutions *should* do the job.

Thanks!

Comment: I prefer the Fanboy Annoyances block list to the Antisocial list, as it blocks more than just social media content (also in-page popups, newsletters, unnecessary links, self promos and other content that clutters sites unnecessarily). See a comparison between the two [here (link)](http://imgur.com/a/bUyhw).

Comment: I can confirm that Ghostery is able to block social media elements. See these screenshots of Ghostery's options page: http://i.imgur.com/PxxRl.png and http://i.imgur.com/yOEbj.png.

Answer (score 4):

You may try Adblock Plus with [Element Hiding Helper](http://adblockplus.org/en/elemhidehelper). Once the elements are blocked, there is a less chance for them to apear again.

Comment: I don't use AdBlock PLUS I use AdBlock LITE! because AdBlock Plus allows so-called "acceptable ads" against cash.

Comment: @gojira You can easily disable that feature in ABP. Just uncheck the "Allow non-intrusive advertising" checkbox.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Anti Social list](http://adversity.uk.to/) of Adblock to remove the annoying social buttons.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what everyone else has suggested, [Disconnect.me](https://disconnect.me) can be another layer added for blocking these services (it's an extension for your browser).